# Javascript delegate

Tags: javascript, delegates

I have the following the code

```
function createDelegate(object, method)
{
    var shim =  function()
    {                   
         method.apply(object, arguments);
    }
    return shim;
}


this.test = 3;   
var pAction = {to: this.test}
this.tmp = createDelegate(this, function()
{
              print("in: " + pAction.to); 
              return pAction.to;
});
print("out: " + this.tmp());
```

But for some reason I get the following result

```
in: 3
out: undefined
```

Anyone knows the reason for this?

Comment: FWIW, your code basically tries to emulate the ES5 `.bind()` method. [Have a look at the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to see their implementation.

Comment: Wat output do you expect in "out" ?

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling. Gonna take a look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create the delegated function you must return the result of the old function:

```
function createDelegate(object, method)
{
 var shim =  function()
 {                  
    return method.apply(object, arguments);
 }
 return shim;
}
```

Comment: Isn't delegating just a closure in JS?